# Pay Google Developer Registration fee.

Tags: android, google-play

IS there any way to pay google developer registration fee without google wallet?
I am trying to pay it through the google wallet but at the time of adding my debit card it said that authentication failed .

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I believe Google Wallet is the only means of payment. Is your card one of the valid ones listed [here](https://support.google.com/wallet/answer/105916)? Otherwise, it may be an issue with the card/information you've inputted. Check out the [Google Wallet Help Center](https://support.google.com/wallet/?hl=en&topic=2446103#topic=3209987).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the **Google Play Cards do not work either** (was just confirmed in chat). So you need to use the methods in [the link @Andy provided](https://support.google.com/wallet/?hl=en&topic=2446103#topic=3209987).